# Security Popup IE8 wistia video

Tags: html, security, iframe, video, https

I had the following iframe which renders the Video.In IE8, I am getting the security popup error.

```
<iframe src="https://fast.wistia.com/embed/iframe/223ewe311111112?videoWidth=310&videoHeight=120&controlsVisibleOnLoad=true&playerColor=1213221&plugin%5Bsocialbar%5D%5Bversion%5D=v1&plugin%5Bsocialbar%5D%5Bbuttons%5D=email-twitter-googlePlus-facebook&plugin%5Bsocialbar%5D%5Blogo%5D=true&plugin%5Bsocialbar%5D%5BtweetText%5D=May%20to%I%20New%Help%20You%20&plugin%5Bsocialbar%5D%5BbadgeUrl%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fwistia.com&plugin%5Bsocialbar%5D%5BbadgeImage%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fprime-cdn.wistia.com%2Fdeliveries%2Fe6e6be3fsdfsdfsdfsdf7e0a69.jpg%3Fimage_crop_resized%3D100x20" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" width="310" height="120"></iframe>
```

I came to know that they updated their IFRAME API on their framework.Will it be a cause for rendering the popup in IE8 only.Using HTTPWATCH plugin in IE8,I found that all resources are rendering HTTPS only.So, because of this iframe tag only it is rendering the popup.I put this iframe tag in seperate HTML page and opened it in IE8 browser.It is showing Security popup.

Comment: iframe `src` is a `<a>` tag ?

Comment: sorry, it is not an <a> tag.Updated the question

Comment: Do you attempt to access the iframe by javascript? it will cause cross-domain security error.

Comment: No, I am not accessing the iframe by javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you better get that example embed code checked out! :) It doesn't look like the iframe src is valid (it leads to a 404 page), which made this a little difficult to test. There are also some weirdnesses like target="_blank" on the iframe, which I don't think is produced by Wistia.

Anyway, I stapled the options onto a different media's embed code and I think I figured out your issue. The domain for the logo in the socialbar is what's causing the security warning.

If you upload your logo in the SuperEmbed Builder then switch to an SSL (under Embed Type > Advanced Options), it will also switch the domain of the logo to one that has a security certificate. I'm guessing that you produced a non-SSL embed, then manually switched it from http: to https:. In many cases this doesn't matter, but it does in this one unfortunately.

My recommendation is to produce the embed code directly from the SuperEmbed Builder and switch SSL on there.

Answer (score 0):

What's the nature of the error you're getting? "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL [URL redacted] from frame with URL [URL redacted]. Domains, protocols and ports must match."

If so, there are a number of threads here at StackOverflow that also mention this error. while annoying, is extremely unlikely to be detrimental to how your site works, it's simply a symptom of having unmatched domains, ports and protocols between the iframe and page its embedded on.

So yeah, as long as the content on the page appears to be fine, you can most likely ignore that particular error.

As an alternative, try the Wistia API embed style, which you can also use SSL with--should help you avoid seeing this.